# How to replace a string in a file?

Tags: python

I have 2 numbers in two similar files.  There is a `new.txt` and `original.txt`.  They both have the same string in them except for a number.  The `new.txt` has a string that says `boothNumber="3"`.  The `original.txt` has a string that says `boothNumber="1"`.

I want to be able to read the `new.txt`, pick the number 3 out of it and replace the number 1 in `original.txt`.

Any suggestions?  Here is what I am trying.

```
import re  # used to replace string
import sys # some of these are use for other code in my program

def readconfig():
    with open("new.text") as f:
        with open("original.txt", "w") as f1:
            for line in f:
                match = re.search(r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+', line)
                for line in f1:
                    pattern = re.search(r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+', line)
                    if re.search(pattern, line):
                        sys.stdout.write(re.sub(pattern, match, line))
```

When I run this, my `original.txt` gets completely cleared of any text.
I did a traceback and I get this:

```
in readconfig
for line in f1:
io.UnsupportedOperationo: not readable
```

**UPDATE**

I tried:

```
def readconfig(original_txt_path="original.txt", 
               new_txt_path="new.txt"):
    with open(new_txt_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            if not ('boothNumber=') in line:
                continue
            booth_number = int(line.replace('boothNumber=', ''))
            # do we need check if there are more than one 'boothNumber=...' line?
            break
    with open(original_txt_path) as f1:
        modified_lines = [line.startswith('boothNumber=') if not line
                          else 'boothNumber={}'.format(booth_number)  
                          for line in f1]
    with open(original_txt_path, mode='w') as f1:
        f1.writelines(modified_lines)
```

And I get error:

```
booth_number = int(line.replace('boothNumber=', ''))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '
(workstationID="1" "1" window=1= area="" extra parts of the line here)\n
```

the "1" after workstationID="1" is where the boothNumber=" " would normally go.  When I open up original.txt, I see that it actually did not change anything.

**UPDATE 3**

Here is my code in full.  Note, the file names are changed but I'm still trying to do the same thing.  This is another idea or revision I had that is still not working:

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput
import re  # used to replace string
import sys # prevents extra lines being inputed in config
           # example: sys.stdout.write


def convertconfig(pattern):                        
    source = "template.config"
    with fileinput.FileInput(source, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            match = r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+'
            sys.stdout.write(re.sub(match, pattern, line))


def readconfig():
    source = "bingo.config"
    pattern = r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+'  # !!!!!!!!!! This probably needs fixed
    with fileinput.FileInput(source, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            if re.search(pattern, line):
                fileinput.close()
                convertconfig(pattern)

def copyfrom(servername):

    source = r'//' + servername + '/c$/remotedirectory'
    dest = r"C:/myprogram"
    file = "bingo.config"
    try:
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, file), os.path.join(dest, file))

    except:
        print ("Error")

    readconfig()


# begin here
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
array = []
with open("serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
    for servername in f:

        copyfrom(servername.strip())
```

bingo.config is my new file
template.config is my original

It's replacing the number in template.config with the literal string "r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+'"

So template.config ends up looking like

```
boothNumber="r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+'"
```

instead of

```
boothNumber="2"
```

Comment: You're writing to stdout instead of a file. You should explicitly open `new.txt` as write, `original.txt` as read. You don't need regex.

Comment: I'm using re because I'm actually importing many configs from a list of computers.  They all have different boothNumbers so I am searching for the pattern in each config to find those numbers and replace my original.text with them each time.  Are there any better alternatives for that?  I put "with open(new.txt", "r") in there and I'm still getting same error.

Comment: `open("original.txt", "w")`... You can't *read* that file, as the error says

Comment: You said - "They both have the same information in them except for a number." And then you are want to replace the number as well.. then why don't you just copy new.txt to original.txt?

Comment: I'm sorry, I need to fix that.  They are slightly different files.  They both have the same string in them that says 'boothNumber="x")' where x is an integer.

Comment: @Prox: please, add example of lines containing `boothNumber`

Comment: <jack Fill workstationID="1" boothNumber="23" window="17" Code="" area="" section="" location="" touchScreen="False" secureWorkstation="false">

Comment: My actual goal is to do this with both boothNumber and window in the above line.  I was working on boothNumber first, then work window into the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find `boothNumber` value we can use next regular expression (checked with [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/xohwzx/1))

```
(?<=\sboothNumber=\")(\d+)(?=\")
```

Something like this should work

```
import re
import sys # some of these are use for other code in my program

BOOTH_NUMBER_RE = re.compile('(?<=\sboothNumber=\")(\d+)(?=\")')
search_booth_number = BOOTH_NUMBER_RE.search
replace_booth_number = BOOTH_NUMBER_RE.sub


def readconfig(original_txt_path="original.txt", 
               new_txt_path="new.txt"):
    with open(new_txt_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            search_res = search_booth_number(line)
            if search_res is None:
                continue
            booth_number = int(search_res.group(0))
            # do we need check if there are more than one 'boothNumber=...' line?
            break
        else:
            # no 'boothNumber=...' line was found, so next lines will fail,
            # maybe we should raise exception like
            # raise Exception('no line starting with "boothNumber" was found')
            # or assign some default value
            # booth_number = -1
            # or just return?
            return

    with open(original_txt_path) as f:
        modified_lines = []
        for line in f:
            search_res = search_booth_number(line)
            if search_res is not None:
                line = replace_booth_number(str(booth_number), line)
            modified_lines.append(line)
    with open(original_txt_path, mode='w') as f:
        f.writelines(modified_lines)
```

## Test

```
# Preparation
with open('new.txt', mode='w') as f:
    f.write('some\n')
    f.write('<jack Fill workstationID="1" boothNumber="56565" window="17" Code="" area="" section="" location="" touchScreen="False" secureWorkstation="false">')

with open('original.txt', mode='w') as f:
    f.write('other\n')
    f.write('<jack Fill workstationID="1" boothNumber="23" window="17" Code="" area="" section="" location="" touchScreen="False" secureWorkstation="false">')

# Invocation
readconfig()

# Checking output
with open('original.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # stripping newline character
        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

gives

```
other
<jack Fill workstationID="1" boothNumber="56565" window="17" Code="" area="" section="" location="" touchScreen="False" secureWorkstation="false">
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do line.contains instead of line.startwith?  It's not working but I think that's because there is also other random data on the same line as boothNumber="x".  The lines don't actually start with that string.  Sorry, I should have specified that.  Maybe "if (boothNumber=') in line"?

Comment: I added an additional comment in my post up top explaining what error I am getting now.

Comment: @Prox: i'm glad